Twilio Studio Flow run via command line
I have a Twilio Studio Flow that runs a few widgets / serverless functions.
It works properly when I call my Twilio number (which is setup to run this flow). However, I'd like be able to run the flow via command line, instead of calling, for debug purposes.
I've found the twilio CLI and Rest API, but when I run something like twilio api:studio:v2:flows:executions:create --flow-sid $FLOW_SID --from $FROM --to $TO, it returns an Execution SID but it looks like it just stays still. How do I trigger input into the execution since one of the first widgets asks for caller input

When you initiate a Twilio Studio Flow using the command twilio api:studio:v2:flows:executions:create, you're indeed creating a new execution via the REST API. This command starts the flow, but it doesn't use the same trigger as incoming calls. You can double-check the trigger also in the Log within Studio:

The easiest workaround would be to draw another connection from the REST API trigger to your first widget.

